# WPF - Adding validation rule on multiple Textboxes with bound text

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

Hopefully I can explain this well.

What I am trying to achieve is to create one validation rule that limits the size of the characters in textbox, and apply it to multiple textboxes, but without adding it inside `Textbox.Text` property in the content of every textbox in the application.

I've created the validation rule:

```
public class TexboxFieldLengthValidationRule : ValidationRule {
    public int MaxLength { private get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
        var result = new ValidationResult(true, null);
        var input = (value ?? string.Empty).ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "This field cannot be empty.");
        }

        return input.Length > MaxLength
            ? new ValidationResult(false, "Maximum number of characters is " + MaxLength + ".")
            : result;
    }
}
```

I have several Textboxes that look like so:

```
    <TextBox
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,5,5,0"
        mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
        mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Remote File Separator (one character maximum)">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding
                Mode="TwoWay"
                NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                Path="Ftp.RemoteFileSeparator"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validation:TexboxFieldLengthValidationRule MaxLength="1" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Is there a way I can apply this validation rule with some kind of bindable property, or a style? Because adding 10 lines of code for every textbox in the solution isn't really nice.

The other way I've found is to throw exception in the setter of a property, and use `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True`, for which I'm not sure how good it is.

Comment: Probably a `Behavior` is what you want.  You could also use `IDataErrorInfo` in view models to deal with field validation.

Comment: I prefer to keep the validation in Model. You mean using AttachedProperties? I think I've read about it but haven't used it exclusively. Thanks for remind me.

Comment: @Desomph: You know that the TextBox has a MaxLength property?

Comment: I do, but I need to represent it visually. Because, people.. :/